# Using jstl <c:when> tag is not evaluating expression correctly

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm trying to use c:choose  tag along with c:when jstl tag in the following code but the  expression is not evaluated correctly. I have a servlet that correctly sets the bean Seller in the session scope.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.seller}">
            <c:out value="${seller.firstName}"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <c:out value="none"/>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</html>
```

The servlet code is below:

```
package com.senachat.presentation;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.senachat.domain.Seller;

public class SenachatServlet extends HttpServlet{

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    resp.setContentType("text/html");

    Seller seller = new Seller();
    seller.setFirstName("John");

    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("seller", seller);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    this.doGet(req, resp);
}
```

}

When the index.jsp page is loaded, the value "none" is printed instead of the value of firstName "John". I cannot identify what am I possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: You say "When the index.jsp page is loaded" .  Do you mean to say that you browse directly to index.jsp?   Or do browse to your Servlet and then are forwarded to index.jsp?

Comment: @rickz was thinking the same, but it can't be that cuz the jsp is in the WEB-INF folder

Comment: Try and use test="${sessionScope.seller != null}" and let us know if anything changes

Comment: I meant when it is forwarded to index.jsp

Comment: @AngeloOparah, I have tried your suggestion, but I get the same result. This is one of those issues that is really frustrating cause I have used this before in older versions of tomcat, servlet/jsp specs and it worked fine. Im currently using tomcat 8.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Something else in your Servlet must be preventing the session from starting. Could you upload the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes I cannot see anything wrong with the code in question. I'm leaning may be towards the jstl version or something of that nature.

Comment: You can debug by printing the session id to the console from the Servlet and to the page in the JSP. They should be the same. Also try ${seller} in the JSP. It should print something.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping guide me to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I realized the expression language statement were not even being evulated.

So I turned to the documentation at the following link https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

It mentionned EL is disabled by default for servlet spec 2.3 and older. And sure enough I declared an older version of servlet spec 2.3 in my web.xml